# Find unserialized type from Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm doing some importing of data from AD/LDAP, and having some issues with the binary attributes returned as `byte[]` in the `ResultPropertyValueCollection` object.

The simplest example is the objectGUID attribute. I need it in a proper GUID object, not a `byte[]`. I can easily say `new Guid(myByteArray)`, but that seems clumsy if there are other binary fields (Im guessing images and such) that are **not** GUIDs.

Is there any clean and tidy way of getting the unserialized type from a `byte[]` without just attempting to create different objects from it? Or better: Can I make LDAP/AD tell me what kind of object it is? I'd like this because I want a generic import that can handle all attributes and map them correctly into my own system.

...This might be sortof an edge case, but if it is possible to do this in a generic way, that would be perfect. If not, I'll probably just stick to try-catching a `new Guid(myByteArray)` for now.

Comment: Arve if you post your code for how you are creating your DirectoryEntry as well as your root.Entry.Properties, DirectorySearcher and your DirectorySearcher Filter and the Searcher.PropertiesToLoad("distinguishedname") you can get the GUID I am doing this right now for BOA in our Active Directory and LDAP environments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check that the byte array is exactly 16 bytes long.  Other than that, a GUID is plainly just an array of 16 bytes, so you can't validate it against any other metric.

As for accidentally deserializing another datatypes byte array, unfortunately this information is usually not stored with the serialized byte array.  The caller is expected to already know what the byte array is, and do the casting themselves.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with one line of code I am currently doing this now in our LDAP/AD environment

```
var sObjectGUID = entry.NativeGuid.ToString();
```

kepp in mind there is more code that I am doing but basically I have a method in our business code that I can't share here but I am doing the check based on if SamAccount exist.

```
public static string SamExist( string domain, string userid)
{
}
```

Comment: You call `Convert.ToString` on a string?

Comment: yes when working with AD I use this on a daily basis with ActiveDirectory when working with DirectoryEntry I just ran and tested it on my work laptop from our dev / stage environment and it works..if the OP would put his code out..I could show him how to get the info he seeks and it's very simple

Comment: I'm not saying `Convert.ToString("xxx")` doesn't work, I'm saying you could just write `"xxx"` instead. Or in your case, `var sObjectGUID = entry.NativeGuid.ToString();` should do the same thing.

Comment: I would have to check it and see.. it's in Production code but I will test it in my Dev environment. 
HVD, you are correct it works..I edited answer.. I may have misunderstood your response.. my apologies

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Im looking for a generic way to handle all binary fields. The GUID was just an example. My code is not really interesting, what I really want to achieve is to put every attribute in AD into a collection with a proper type. That's why I'd like the super-parsing of byte[]s.